# How do I get the permalink of a specific Facebook Social Plugin Comment through the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Consider the following piece of dummy data returned from the Graph API for Facebook's Commenting Social Plugin:

```
{
        "id": "387539086359_14842802",
        "from": {
           "name": "Manja Elis",
           "id": "1168990251"
        },
        "message": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Manja-Elis/151029671610040",
        "created_time": "2010-11-24T07:06:06+0000",
        "comments": {
           "data": [
              {
                 "id": "494442921359",
                 "from": {
                    "name": "J Reigy T II",
                    "id": "100001234540335"
                 },
                 "message": "~ www.jareta.name ~",
                 "created_time": "2011-01-30T00:04:30+0000"
              }
           ],
           "count": 1
        }
     }
```

How can I generate the permalink to this specific comment so that it can be bumped to the top of the discussion?

I know that the first id# "387539086359_14842802" is the ID of the comment thread as a whole, but now I need the specific ID of the actual first comment so that I can properly link to it. The problem is, that 3rd piece of ID information is nowhere to be found.

What I find funny is that the reply comment with id# "494442921359" is the correct ID for that reply, but there is no equivalent offered for the original post - why??? Worse yet, Facebook ignores links to any comments that aren't the first in a new sub-thread so linking to the reply instead is useless to me.

So to clarify:

Comment id of first post in the thread is : 387539086359_14842802_????

Comment id of the reply to this post would be: 387539086359_14842802_494442921359 but unfortunately FB ignores reply IDs so it is useless to me.

Can anyone tell me how I programatically get this ???? ID for permalink generation purposes?

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this, I found out the Javascript was returning the ID I needed so I had to combine that info with what I collected PHP side to complete the picture. It was a bit of an extra step and crosses to client side but that was the only solution at the time.